# plotting with cbrange other than [0:255] on top of an external image

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I'd like to draw a plot of data file consisting of (*x*, *y*, *z*, *color*), just as with

```
set cbrange [cb_min:cb_max]
splot 'path.dat' palette with lines
```

but I'd also like to put an external image (PNG or JPEG) on the xy-plane, as with

```
set zrange [0:]
set xyplane at 0
splot 'image.png' binary filetype=png with rgbimage
```

So I'd like to combine these in one `splot`:

```
splot 'image.png' binary filetype=png with rgbimage, 'path.dat' palette with lines
```

The problem is that `rgbimage` seems to use the current setting of `cbrange` for mapping the RGB values from the image to the plotted color, and distorts the colors of the image if `cbrange` is not `[0:255]` (whether through autoscaling or not), whereas the  `path.dat` requires a different `cbrange`. For example, if `cb_min` is above 255, the image will appear all black, while `cb_max` below 0 will render the image all white.

Is there a way I can plot `path.dat` with an appropriate range of colors while preserving the original color of `image.png`?

Comment: I would try to plot the external image _first_; then set the color ranges; and finally plot the data with `replot "path.dat"`

Comment: @vagoberto: `replot "path.dat"` doesn't merely add another plot on top of the existing one; it redraws the previous one. ("_[Arguments specified after a **replot** command will be added onto the last **plot** or **splot** command (with an implied ',' separator) before it is repeated.](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node150.html)_") So setting `cbrange` later also changes the color of the external image already drawn.

Comment: What about rescaling the colorbar? e.g. `set cbrange [0:255]`, then plot the data with rescaled colors, something like `splot 'image' ..., 'path.dat' u 1:2:3:(255*($4-cb_min)/(cb_max-cb_min))`, and finally add the corresponding tics in the colorbar with `set cbtics ('0' cb_min, '255' cb_max)`

Comment: With this type of issue, the usual gnuplot solution is to use `set multiplot`: then gnuplot simply overlays the new `plot`/`splot` commands on the output of previous ones. The trouble is that the [xyz]ranges need to be right from the first command on. This should be the case for your plot, except maybe for z which you should set manually. If you post your files somewhere, I can give you a MWE.

Comment: @vagoberto: Thanks, I found that the other way round works more easily: `set cbrange [cb_min:cb_max]` followed by `splot 'image.png' binary filetype=png using (f($1)):(f($2)):(f($3)) with rgbimage, ...`, where `f(c)=c/255*(cb_max-cb_min)+cb_min`; then you don't need to do `set cbtics` manually.

Comment: @Joce: Thanks; I see that method can also be useful.